# Pandoc: Conditional breaks when converting docx to markdown

Tags: html, ms-word, markdown, html-entities, pandoc

I have a docx document which contains conditional breaks (`Ctrl + -`). I'm converting them to markdown and later (with jekyll) to HTML. Unfortunately, the conditional breaks are lost. A workaround is to edit the generated markdown document and insert `&shy;`, but this is not a solution since I need to generate the markdown from the docx regulary.

How can I tell pandoc to keep the conditional breaks?

Edit: It does not only occur when converting to markdown, the conditional breaks are also lost when converting directly to HTML.

Comment: Are you sure they are "lost." Or is the Unicode character still there, just ignored by the browser and/or text editor you are using. My expectation would be that the Unicode soft hyphen character (`U+00AD`) would simply be ignored by Pandoc and be passed through unaltered. You would then need to do a search-and-replace on the output. Or does Word not use the Unicode soft hyphen character (`U+00AD`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Word doesn't use the unicode character 'SOFT HYPHEN' (U+00AD) but instead creates it's own XML element `<w:softHyphen/>` internally in it's docx format.

A [pandoc issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2415) has been filed to adjust the docx reader.